# How to get a date value from django DateField forms and save it in mongodb?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have a datefield in my django forms and now I need to get that value and save it in mongodb at views.py.Thing is I don't know how to get a date value from django forms and save in mongodb inside a views.py

how to get this value in my views.py

```
forms.py:
from django import forms
DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'form-control datepicker'})

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    from_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())

views.py:
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        from_date = form.cleaned_data['from_date']

        db.query.insert({
               #What should I need to do here .. ?

        })
```

Comment: This question is either trivial or impossible to answer. Where *exactly* are you having trouble? What *do* you know how to do? Have you done the tutorials?

Comment: Still not possible to answer. You **quite clearly** already have the value, so I don't know why you say you don't know how to get it from the form. But how do you want to insert it? Do you have a document?

Answer (score 0):

In the insert query you have to pass datetime object instead of date.

```
db.query.insert({'from_date':datetime.combine(from_date, datetime.min.time())})
```

You will need to import `datetime` from `datetime` module to execute the above query